Computing coset representatives for a product of commuting subgroups
As part of writing some code to explore the symmetries of certain combinatorial objects, I'm running into a few questions that are probably elementary group theory.
I have subgroups $A$ and $B$ of a parent group $G$, with the property that $ab=ba$ for every $a\in A,b\in B$, so the subgroup $H$ generated by $A\cup B$ is just the set $\{ab:a\in A,b\in B\}$. I also have $A\cap B=\{1\}$, so I guess we can think of $H$ as the direct product $A\times B$. (Also, if it helps, I have finite generating sets for $A$ and $B$, and all the generators are involutions.)
I would like to implement a "coset-identifying" function $c_H$ on $G$ with the property that if $xH=yH$ then $c_H(x)=c_H(y)$. I don't need $c_H(x)$ to be an element of $xH$ (or even of $G$), but this seems like a natural approach.
A straightforward way to do this is to enumerate all the elements of $xH$ (by enumerating $H$, by enumerating $A$ and $B$ in nested loops) and take $c_H(x)$ to be the smallest element with respect to some total ordering of $G$.
Is there a more efficient way to do this (with runtime $O(|A|+|B|)$ instead of $|A|\times|B|$, say)?
At first I thought one of the following would work, given analogous functions $c_A$ and $c_B$:

Define $c_H(x)=c_B(c_A(x))$.
Define $c_H(x)=xab$ where $a,b$ satisfy $c_A(x)=xa$ and $c_B(x)=xb$.

The intuition is to "canonicalize the $A$ part and the $B$ part separately", but I'm starting to think this doesn't work. If we have have $xH=yH$ but not $xA=yA$, then evaluating $c_A(x)$ and $c_A(y)$ doesn't do anything useful since they're "canonicalizing in different cosets".

This depends a bit on what your group elements are. The slickest way is if you can define a suitable group action on combinatorial objects in which $H$ is the point stabilizer of $\omega$. Then the action image $\omega^x$ defines the coset.
Otherwise, what e.g. GAP does for permutation groups is to define "minimal" coset elements and use the determination of such minimal elements as coset identification. Reference:

Hulpke, Alexander; Linton, Steve: Total ordering on subgroups and cosets.Proceedings of the 2003 International Symposium on Symbolic and Algebraic Computation, 156–160. ACM


Thanks! Yes, actually, $G$ is the symmetry group of a regular abstract polytope, and the cosets of $H$ correspond to faces of a given dimension. For some polytopes, the group elements are matrices in $O(n)$ and I can represent a face by its center point in $\Bbb R^n$, but in other cases (including polytopes given by generators in the atlas - a cool GAP-based project!), it seems necessary to "recover the faces from the group". I'm curious if there's a clever way to take advantage of the representation of $H$ as a product of the two smaller subgroups.

The "Minimal representative" calculation will use a stabilizer chain for AxB and thus implicitly use the direct product structure.

Oh, neat. I'll read the article and try to understand how that works. I guess I need to study stabilizer chains.
